# Fade in/out li elements with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanna to fade and out my li elements with delay except the first-child.

Here is my jQuery

```
$(function(){
     function fadeMyContent() {

         $("#fff li:first").fadeIn(700).delay(2000).fadeOut(700,
             function() {    
                     $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
                     fadeMyContent();    
             });
      }
     fadeMyContent();
});
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r6oth6ak/)

Comment: Just asking: why not the first? It looks good. Won't you need it to fade the first as part of the loop?

Comment: @Cory I want to start the animation at the beginning, but the first li has lot of delay, i just want to apply the delay for the second and the rest.

Comment: i suppose you could add a counter (i) and have a separate loop on the first run through (when i=0) and have a shorter delay. After that it runs normal.

Comment: @Cory Can you provide me an example, i'm beginner

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well then I think this can help you.

```
$(function(){
 function fadeMyContent() {
     $("#fff li").each(function(i, j){
         if($(this).text() != "first"){
     $("#fff li:first").fadeIn(700).delay(2000).fadeOut(700,
         function() {    
                 $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
                 fadeMyContent();    
         });
         }
     });
  }
 fadeMyContent();
});
```

Just give it a try and let me know if this is what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

this counts the loops and allows you to change the fades on the first time through

```
 $(function(){
var i = 0
 function fadeMyContent() {
     if (i == 0) {

       $("#fff li:first").fadeIn(700).delay(1000).fadeOut(700,
         function() {    
                 $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
                 fadeMyContent();    
         });

     } else {
       $("#fff li:first").fadeIn(700).delay(2000).fadeOut(700,
         function() {    
                 $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
                 fadeMyContent();    
         });
     }

     i = 1
  }
 fadeMyContent();
 });
```

here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r6oth6ak/5/

Comment: one catch, though--it will keep counting forever (until the page loads again). you could change that last line to `i = 1` to stop the count after the first time. `